# Binary file prints the last element twice?

Tags: c, file, printing, binaryfiles

I have a binary file loaded with 100 movies (struct Movie, I got the data from an array of also 100 movies), and when I want to print it, it prints the data of the last movie twice. I use a variable in both functions to know how many times I cycled (when I export the data from the array to the file, and when I print the file), and it seems to load the data correctly (counter = 100) but when I print it, counter = 101.

It's a simple program so I don't know why this is happening.
Can you help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 100

typedef struct{
    int id;
    char title[100];
    char director[100];
    char genre[100];
    int likes;
    int number_of_voters;
    float average_score;
    int year;
    int cost;
    char color[100];
    float ratingW;
}Movie;

typedef struct{
     Movie movies[SIZE];
     int cant;  //Number of elements (100)
}Array;

void ExportToBinary(Array a, FILE* f);
void ShowMovie(Movie mov);
void PrintBinaryFile(FILE* f);

int main(){
    Array a;  //Already loaded with 100 movies, (index 0 to 99)
    FILE* binFile;
    ExportToBinary(a, binFile);
    PrintBinaryFile(binFile);
    return 0;
}

//Exports the data from an array into a binary file
void ExportToBinary(Array a, FILE* f){
    f = fopen("movies.dat", "wb");
    Movie reg;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < a.cant; i++){
        // Copy the data from the array into the reg variable, and then into the file
        reg.id = a.movies[i].id;
        strcpy(reg.title, a.movies[i].title);
        strcpy(reg.director, a.movies[i].director);
        strcpy(reg.genre, a.movies[i].genre);
        reg.likes = a.movies[i].likes;
        reg.number_of_voters = a.movies[i].number_of_voters;
        reg.average_score = a.movies[i].average_score;
        reg.year = a.movies[i].year;
        reg.cost = a.movies[i].cost;
        strcpy(reg.color, a.movies[i].color);
        reg.ratingW = a.movies[i].ratingW;
        fwrite(&reg, sizeof(reg), 1, f);
    }
    fclose(f);
    printf("Binary file loaded with %d movies\n", i); //This works, it shows i=100
}

//Shows a single movie
void ShowMovie(Movie mov){
    printf("///////////////////////////////////\n");
    printf("Id: %d\n", mov.id);
    printf("Title: %s", mov.title);
    printf("Director: %s", mov.director);
    printf("Genre: %s", mov.genre);
    printf("Likes: %d\n", mov.likes);
    printf("Number of voters: %d\n", mov.number_of_voters);
    printf("Average score: %.2f\n", mov.average_score);
    printf("Year: %d\n", mov.year);
    printf("Cost: $%d\n", mov.cost);
    printf("Color or BW: %s", mov.color);
    printf("Rating: %.2f\n", mov.ratingW);
    printf("///////////////////////////////////\n");
}

//Prints a binary file
void PrintBinaryFile(FILE* f){
    f = fopen("movies.dat", "rb");
    Movie reg;
    int j = 0;
    while (!feof(f)){
        fread(&reg, sizeof(reg), 1, f);
        ShowMovie(reg);
        j++;
    }
    printf("Printed elements: %d\n", j);  //Shows j=101 elements, that's the problem
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: @user3121023 I don't understand what to use then

Comment: @user3121023 Thank you, I changed it for while ((fread(&reg, sizeof(reg), 1, f)) == 1) and it works.